# Loops inside loops?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

Trying to read four different columns across two files and assign it appropriately. Can anyone help?

languagefile.txt reads:
Language isocode

english.txt reads:
field value

I want it to loop through both files and associate the isocode & filename & field & value.

I have a while loop that does the english.txt file:

```
cat english.txt| while read FIELD VALUE; do
GET https://googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=$mykey&q=$VALUE&source=en&target=es
echo "$FIELD "$VALUE"; done
```

however I need to extend that to account for the languagefile too. So it would do like:

```
cat english.txt| while read FIELD VALUE; do
GET https://googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=$mykey&q=$VALUE&source=en&target=$isocode
echo "$ISO $FIELD "$VALUE" >> $Language.txt; done
```

I hope this makes sense. I ultimately just need to have it do it for each language and iso code. Not sure on the best approiaach

Comment: Is GET a command ?  And also :  read a b c : this means take first field in a, 2nd field in b, and rest of the line in c. (fields separated by IFS, by default spaces, tabs and newlines). Not sure that is what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you properly, the simplest solution would likely make use of `paste`:

```
while read -r iso field value; do
    # do something with $iso $field and $value
done < <(paste languagefile.txt english.txt)
```

Note, that things will get a lot more hairy if any of the input data fields can contain whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, let me rephrase, and yes GET is a command.

File1 contains:
language iso

File2 contains:
field value

I ultimately want to have the end result as:
language.txt:
iso field value

Where language.txt comes from file1, field one.

So it needs to be like:
For each time it reads $language, do a GET request with $field $value $iso(that corresponds with the line in $language) then input results into $language.txt in the format $iso $field $value

Comment: You should edit your original question instead of adding an explanation as one 'answer'. As people start voting on the answers, your additional explanation will get sorted lower, so others might not see it.